# order by with parameters in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use variables in `mysql` query:

```
SET @resultsPerPage = 10;
SET @offset = 0;
```

and in query:

```
ORDER BY u.USER_NAME ASC LIMIT @offset, @resultsPerPage
```

the Error I receive is :

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

any suggestions?

Comment: You're not trying to order by parameters. You're trying to limit by parameters. You can't. Not like this, anyway.

Comment: You cannot use variables in the `LIMIT` clause of a MySQL statement. You have to think of a workaround. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: well, i'm trying to achieve 2 things:
1) using params for ordering
2) paginate using the database, later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible workaround for achieving pagination is using variables in the following way:

```
SET @resultsPerPage = 10; -- Display 10 records per page
SET @offset = 0;          -- Display the first page

SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn, u.*
   FROM mytable AS u
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0)
   ORDER BY u.USER_NAME) AS t
WHERE t.rn >= @offset * @resultsPerPage + 1 AND
      t.rn <= (@offset + 1) * @resultsPerPage
```